# Detect a string in several cells of Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using this formula to detect a string in a specific cell of my Google Sheet.

```
=IF (REGEXMATCH('Mysheet'!GE2;"yes");"X";"O")
```

But now I want to verify if I can find that string "yes" in three other cells at the same time GF2,GH2,GI2. How to do that?

Comment: ...Also for non-range cells like "GE2,HA2..."

Answer (score 1):

This formula detects if **at least one** cell in the range contains "yes"

```
=if(or(arrayformula(regexmatch('Mysheet'!GE2:GI2; "yes"))); "X"; "O")
```

This one detects if **every** cell in the range contains "yes":

```
=if(and(arrayformula(regexmatch('Mysheet'!GE2:GI2; "yes"))); "X"; "O")
```

Explanation: `arrayformula` applies the `regexmatch` to every cell of the range, returning an array of True/False values. These are joined by OR or AND logic, accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for all theses explainations ! And if i want to detect cells who are not in range, like GE2, HA2 ?

Comment: Again use and or or as needed. `or(regexmatch(GE2, "yes"), regexmatch(HA2, "yes))`

Comment: Ok so ive tried first :
`=IF(OR((A2=1);(A2=2));"OUI";"NON")`

And after :
`=IF(OR(REGEXMATCH('Sheet'!AJ2;"ok");REGEXMATCH('Sheet'!AE2;"ok"));"OUI";"NON")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @if... for his help.

```
=IF(OR(REGEXMATCH('Sheet'!AJ2;"ok");REGEXMATCH('Sheet'!AE2;"ok"));"1";"2")
```