# How do I get REGEXMATCH to look for one term across a range of cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

In Google Sheets I have the following formula:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(B1;"offers");"spring";0)
```

If the cell B1 contains the text "offers" the output will be "spring", otherwise the output will be "0". This works fine but now I want the formular to look at B1 and C1 and if either of them contains "offers" the output should be "spring".

**Example Output with formula in column D:**

| B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test offers test | lorem ipsum | spring |
| lorem ipsum | test offers test | spring |
| lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | 0 |

I tried the obvious using

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(B1:C1;"offers");"spring";0)
```

but it gives back a `#VALUE!`

In the second step I want to use this formula in a nested if function like here:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(B1;"offers");"spring";IF(REGEXMATCH(B1;"shop");"summer";0))
```

Comment: Your example nowhere _contains the text "offers"_.

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be:

```
=if(and(arrayformula(regexmatch(B1:C1; "(^| )offers( |$)"))); "spring"; "O")
```

As modified from user6655984's answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48196364/detect-a-string-in-several-cells-of-google-sheets).  Note I altered the regex to ensure the pattern you are looking to match is preceded by the start of the line or a space, and is proceeded by a space or the end of the line which ensures it does not fall in the middle of a larger string and handles being at the start or end of the main string.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(B1&C1; "offers"); "spring"; 0)
```

arrayformula:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(B1:B&C1:C; "offers"); "spring"; 0))
```